# Primeng p-dropdown should close on scrolling document page

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

Had p-dropdown which is inside p-table as column header. While scrolling p-table, p-dropdown should close.

```
<p-table #dTable [columns]="cols">
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
  <tr class="table-header-row">
    <th *ngFor="let col of cols" [ngStyle]="{'width': col.widthPer ? col.widthPer + '%' : col.widthPx + 'px'}">
      {{col.header}}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-header-row">
    <th *ngFor="let col of cols" [ngSwitch]="col.field"
      [ngStyle]="{'width': col.widthPer ? col.widthPer + '%' : col.widthPx + 'px'}">
      <input [(ngModel)]="designNameFilterValue" *ngSwitchCase="'designName'" pInputText class="design-name-filter"
        (keyup)="refreshTree(hideNonSelected, defaultFilter)">
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'cost'">
        Value >= {{cost| currency}}
        <i class="fa fa-close"
          (click)="costFilterValue = 0; refreshTree(hideNonSelected, defaultFilter);"
          style="cursor:pointer" *ngIf="costFilterValue"></i>
        <p-slider [(ngModel)]="cost" [min]="0" [max]="maxCost"
          (onSlideEnd)="refreshTreeTable(hideNonSelected, defaultFilter)"></p-slider>
      </div>
      <p-dropdown class="filter" *ngSwitchCase="'risk'" [options]="filterdropdown" (click)="hide()"
        [(ngModel)]="FilterValue" (onChange)="refreshTree(hideNonSelected, defaultFilter)">
      </p-dropdown>
      <p-dropdown class="state-filter" *ngSwitchCase="'state'" [options]="stateItemsForFilterDropDown"
        (click)="hide()" [(ngModel)]="defaultFilter"
        (onChange)="refreshTree(hideNonSelected, defaultFilter)">
      </p-dropdown>
    </th>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Please assist on this.

Comment: This more like support/feature request for PrimeNG. Suggest you to raise request there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also ran in a similar requirement, and after implementing that feature. We realized its not the valid one, considering the below situation.

Think about Mobile users and drop down have the search or filter feature with an input box.

So whenever the user focuses on the input field it will open the drop-down and at the same time, it opens the mobile keypad that reduced the viewport and fire scroll event. And on the scroll, you want to close the drop-down. Considering the above situation it will be in a loop (open-close) that we have to avoid. And if you have only desktop users than its okay.

So if you have only a desktop user, you implement this

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component , Inject} from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { HostListener} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  cities1 = [];
  constructor() {
    this.cities1 = [
            {label:'Select City', value:null},
            {label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}},
            {label:'Rome', value:{id:2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'}},
            {label:'London', value:{id:3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN'}},
            {label:'Istanbul', value:{id:4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'}},
            {label:'Paris', value:{id:5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}}
        ];
  }
  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    const ele = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    ele.click();
  }
}
```

here is stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-dropdowns-bug-jekbnz)

Comment: we had only desktop users. I can use your implementation. Can you please provide solution

Comment: @Nazeer_hanne updated my answer, you can refine it more if you want to use a global handler for the app.

Comment: How do I do the same for horizontal scroll? I mean scroll in the prime-ng table, not window

Comment: You can find or focus any element with # or just by id, where you want to move the scroll on the left. It will be the same way. Or share stackblitz.